# Python pip not working on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, version

I can't install new packages using pip. In fact, I can't even get pip to run properly. Here's the error message from the Windows command prompt using Python 3.6:

```
 Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
 (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

 C:\Python36>python get-pip.py

 Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python36\lib\site-packages


 C:\Python36>pip --version

 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\python36\Lib\site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os

  File "c:\python36\Lib\os.py", line 409

    yield from walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: 1) make sure you start CMD as an administrator 2) do you have more than 1 copy of python installed? that can mess things up.

Comment: I have several versions of python installed. But I'm running from the python36 folder. What/where should I clean up?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best thing to do aside from removing all versions and reinstalling the one you want.  Ideally what you have should work, but it's happened to me when I simply have 2 versions installed, all kinds of things wonky start happening :)